# Creating an edgelist dataframe from a dataframe to create a graph in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to construct a graph which looks like this:

[image]

The dataset looks like this:

```
title | text            | type      | userid |topic_id     | rowid
------------------------------------------------------------------
A     | I like...       | Post      | 67340  |001          |05461
C     | I wish...       | Question  | 34183  |001          |f0996
C     | review1         | Question  | a7869  |001          |1341-
C     | review2         | Replies   | 5769   |001          |66303-
C     | review3         | Answer    | 67340  |001          |31740
C     | Detecting...    | Answer    | 28524  |001          |20221
C     | review1         | Replied   | 80445  |001          |f8680
B     | Let's..         | Post      | 4fcd   |002          |01171
C     | New...          | Replies   | 5769   |002          |817607
```

I want to create an edgelist that looks like this:

```
from  |  to    |     relation          |topic_id    |initiator_id | attribute
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
34183 | 67340  |  Commented: I wish... | 001        |67340        |A: I like...
a7869 | 67340  |  Commented: review1   | 001        |NA           |NA
5769  | 67340  |  Replied: review2     | 001        |NA           |NA
67340 | 5769   |  Answered: review3    | 001        |NA           |NA
28524 | 5769   |  Answered: Detecting..| 001        |NA           |NA
80445 | 67340  |  Replied: review1     | 001        |NA           |NA
5769  | 4fcd   |  Replied: New...      | 002        |4fcd         |B: New..
```

The `title == B` is a new topic in this group that has to visualized separately.

I have tried the followling:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(topic_id) %>% 
  transmute(from = id,
            relation = case_when(commentable_type == "Post" ~ "Asked",
                                 commentable_type == "Question" ~ "Commented",
                                 commentable_type == "Replies" ~ "Replied",
                                 commentable_type == "Answer" ~ "Answered"),
to = case_when(relation == "Commented" | relation == "Replied" ~ replace(user_pseudo_id), case_when(relation == "Asked")
            relation = paste(relation, text, sep = ': ')
            
            ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-topic_id)
```

I could achieve the `from` and `relation` column so far.
The "to" column would connect like:
if the `userid` has `type == 'Question' | type == 'Replies'` then `userid` of `type == Post` would come. And if `userid` has `type == 'Answer'` then `userid` of `type == Replies` appearing immediately above it would come.

Finding it difficult to put the "to" column.

Data:

```
df <- tribble(~title, ~text, ~type, ~userid, ~topic_id , ~rowid
"A",    "I like...",    NA,     "67340", "001", "05461"
"C",    "I wish...",    "Question",     "c912", "001", "f0996"
"C",    "review1",  "Replies",  "a7869", "001", "1341-"
"C",    "review2",  "Replies",  "5769", "001", "66303-"
"C",    "review3",  "Answer",   "67340", "001", "31740"
"C",    "Detecting...",     "Answer",   "28524", "001", "20221"
"C",    "review1",  "Answer",   "80445", "001", "f8680"
"B",    "Let's..",  NA,     "4fcd", "002", "01171"
"C",    "New...",   "Replies",  "5769", "002", "817607")
```

Comment: It looks like you need some kind of ID which connects `from` and `to`, but you don't have it. I don't see any way for (in the example of the first row) an algorithm to determine when a comment goes from 34183 to 67340.

Comment: I have updated my question with an ID. it was present in the original data.